# How to get a header staying at the top and a line fitting the space between itself and below content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out:

1. Why the h6 tag isn't aligning itself at the top rather than the middle (as it has `justify-self: flex start`)
2. How to make the red line below h6 fill the space between itself and the h2 tag below it (and be responsive)

Does anyone know why (1) isn't working, and how (2) could be achieved? I can't think of another way other than an absolute position for the pseudo element, but presumably this cannot resize if there's more text below or when the browser window resizes?

The demo is below:

```css
#container {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}
h6 {
  position: relative;
  justify-self: flex-start;
}
h6:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  height: 4em;
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <h6>should align at top</h6>
  <h2>Should be the start of the central text area</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ne verear incorrupte interpretaris, est at justo habemus. Ne paulo atomorum his, cu has illum everti fierent, eos dicit audiam ea.</p>
  <p>Illud fabulas an sit. Et est case reque deleniti, ubique constituam te quo. Prima dolorum deleniti vis in, no eos senserit salutandi.</p>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/OJLwdPm

Thanks for any help and ideas here.

Comment: 1) justify-content: flex-start  (.container);   2) height: 100% and media queries

Comment: In flexbox layouts, this property is ignored [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the h6 tag isn't aligning itself at the top rather than the middle (as it has justify-self: flex start)

`justify-self` - is a property from CSS Grid. It does not work in Flexbox

> display: flex;

You do not need a flexbox for the container in this case, since the child elements are block and will be located under each other

> How to make the red line below h6 fill the space between itself and the h2 tag below it (and be responsive)

Not sure if I understood the task correctly. Did you mean that? (Result below)

---

**UPDATED**

> h2 and paragraph tags should align centrally in the div but the h6 be at the top

I had to add another block to align the content vertically. It can be done without it, but it seems that it’s easier.

> the red line needs to be vertical rather than horizontal, and fill the space between the h6 at the top and h2 in the middle of the div

The height of this line starts from h2 and goes up, and at the top for h6 a background is set that hides the red line

**Updated Result**

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 900px;
  min-height: 350px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.inner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <h6>should align at top</h6>
  <div class="inner">
    <h2>Should be the start of the central text area</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei ne verear incorrupte interpretaris, est at justo habemus. Ne paulo atomorum his, cu has illum everti fierent, eos dicit audiam ea.</p>
    <p>Illud fabulas an sit. Et est case reque deleniti, ubique constituam te quo. Prima dolorum deleniti vis in, no eos senserit salutandi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/yLBqZgQ?editors=1100)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I dont think I was entirely clear, sorry, but the start of the h2 and paragraph tags should align centrally in the div but the h6 be at the top, hence the need for flex. Also, the red line needs to be vertical rather than horizontal, and fill the space between the h6 at the top and h2 in the middle of the div